# Check for content change with ajax, and replace with jQuery only if change is detected?

Tags: jquery

Right now I run my code every 10 second checking for change and replacing the div. This works fine, but I use a jQuery animation together with this div and that means it breaks the animation every 10 seconds because of the div being replaced.

This is the current code:

```
function autoRefresh() {
$.ajax({
  success: function(data) {
    // Find div id #vs
    var result = $('<div />').append(data).find('div#vs').html();
    $('div#vs').html(result);
  }
});
}
autoRefresh();
// Refresh at page load and every 10000 milliseconds / 10 seconds
var auto_refresh = setInterval(autoRefresh, 10000);
```

Is it possible to only do the append (replacement) of the div when a change has been detected? So is there a way to instead of every 10 seconds replacing the div, just do a check against the current div, and if not change is detected, nothing is done?

Comment: How is the animation being applied ? does it alter the `style` attributes of some elements ? does it add/remove classes ? Because in both these cases there is change in the DOM if you compare them. So how do you know it is the same ?

Comment: I pasted the animation part to CodePen, check it out here: https://codepen.io/jockebq/pen/vbXGWV EDIT: What I would like to be able to check against is if a new div with the class `vs-content` is added or if it is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real issue here is that the plugin/animation you use moves DOM nodes around (re-orders them) so the actual html will always (*almost*) be different to the ajax response.

You could store the initial html stucture to a variable and compare/refresh when an ajax response arrives.

Something like

```js
var latestVShtml = ''; // variable to store the html
function autoRefresh() {
  $.ajax({
    success: function(data) {
      // Find div id #vs
      var result = $('<div />').append(data).find('div#vs').html();
      if (latestVShtml !== result) { // check if html is modified
        $('div#vs').html(result); // update the DOM 
        latestVShtml = result; // update with the last instance of the html
      }
    }
  });
}

autoRefresh();
// Refresh at page load and every 10000 milliseconds / 10 seconds
var auto_refresh = setInterval(autoRefresh, 10000);
```

Comment: Wow thanks, that works exactly like I hoped it would! Thank you for explaining the process, it was very helpful!